# Is accessing elements via ref in Aurelia scoped to component?

Tags: javascript, scope, aurelia, ref

Let's say I have component in which I reference and work with some elements.
If the parent will contain two instances of the same component, am I guaranteed that both components will correctly reference it's own children?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is guaranteed the refs in an individual component instance will not interfere with refs in another component instance.

`ref` literally adds a property to the component instance's view model with the name specified by the `ref` attribute's value.  Since each component instance has it's own view-model instance, multiple instances of components using ref do not interfere with each other.